# inconsistent 'go list' display issue

Tags: go, package, grpc, protoc

When running from utils directory, `go list -f` returns nothing.

```
user@linux:~/go/src/bitbucket.org/utils> go list -f '{{ .Dir }}' -m github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
user@linux:~/go/src/bitbucket.org/utils> go list -m github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.16.0
```

However, running from another directory, it returns expected.

```
user@linux:~/go/src/proto-api> go list -f '{{ .Dir }}' -m github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
/home/user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.16.0
```

It looks like `-f` is getting the file from `go/pkg`.   `go/pkg/mod` was cleaned using `go clean -x -modcache`  earlier for clean-slate purpose.  Tried `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go` command and it did not work.